# java split does not get empty when backslash separator

Tags: java

i have to split a string based on backslash separator
i have the following value

```
value=Alex\\patricia
```

and the value in the middle sometimes is valued ,but in this case does not have a value ,it s ignored by java
instead of having three tokens ,i have only two .

```
String[] tokens = StringUtils.split(value, '\\');
```

so i get

```
tokens[0]=Alex
tokens[1]=Alex=patricia
```

thanks

Comment: The issue is due to the backslashes which is also a escape character in Java

Comment: @Ananth, no, it's not that. It would do the same with any character. That's how `StringUtils`'s version of `split` works.

Comment: @Anath yes i confirm that it does the same thing with any seprator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try just using standard java classes

```
    String value="Alex\\patricia";
    String[] tokens = value.split("\\\\");
    for (String str : tokens) System.out.println(str);
```

**output**

```
Alex
patricia
```

Comment: I fell for the same trap in my (now fixed) answer, but `value` should really be `"Alex\\\\patricia"` to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

That's how [`split`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#split-java.lang.String-char-) from `StringUtils` works

> Adjacent separators are treated as one separator

You can use Java's `String` [`split`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) instead.

```
String value = "Alex\\\\patricia";
String[] tokens = value.split("\\\\"); // must be escaped since it's a regex
```

Example jshell session:

```
jshell> String value="Alex\\\\patricia";
value ==> "Alex\\\\patricia"

jshell> String[] tokens = value.split("\\\\");
tokens ==> String[3] { "Alex", "", "patricia" }
```